# Do any package managers come installed default in NetBSD?

Tags: package-management, netbsd

I am using NetBSD - I know ports and pkgsrc are available as package managers, but do these or any others come pre-installed in NetBSD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe everything needed for binary install of pkgsrc is bundled as default, but if you want pkgsrc source you have to check out the code.

I do not think ports is a default for NetBSD.

http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html#docs